# Android: How to use LIGHTEN, DARKEN, OVERLAY Porter-Duff Mode in paint below API 28

Tags: android, canvas, porter-duff

I need to blend image with paint tools in different ways. I'm using different Porter-Duff Modes but as the title says, LIGHTER, DARKEN, OVERLAY blending modes are not working in the devices of API 28 or lower since these operations aren't supported for some [hardware acceleration limitation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#unsupported). I want to know how can I apply these in API 28 or below? is there any trick I'm missing? Please help. Thanks.

Note: I can use GpuImage filter but I want to move one bitmap on canvas with onTouchEvent and change the opacity of paint.